# How much say do the actors of the Doctor have in how (s)he is portrayed?

Tags: doctor-who, actors

Whenever a new actor portrays a new incarnation of the Doctor, the Doctor has like a completely new character and basically nothing in common with the last incarnation. How much saying does the actor have on the character of the new incarnation?

E.g., do they get the scripts and have to play out whatever is written down? Do they get the scripts and can give feedback that might be included or would it even be that, before they start filming the first episode with the new Doctor, the actor and authors have a workshop figuring out how the Doctor is portrayed, how he'd act in situations and how he'll develop?

Please answer with quotes from people involved in the production or that have a good insight into production (e.g. a documentary about Doctor Who from a professional source). Answers like "usually, it's like X" or "depends on how much the actor wants to get involved" are not what I seek. We now have the fifth Doctor since 2005, there is probably a policy how the onboarding happens (or maybe it's more like things have become custom on how it happens).

Comment: "the Doctor has like a completely new character and basically nothing in common with the last incarnation" — that might be over-stating things.

Comment: "We now have the fifth Doctor since 2005" — if we're counting the Meta-Crisis Doctor, the War Doctor, and Jo Martin's Doctor, we've got eight.

Comment: It depends. I'm pretty certain that the actor and the writers usually never meet (except for the showrunner).

Comment: @OrangeDog Maybe it's the showrunner discussing this with the actor. But there are some known names within the list of Doctor Who actors and I think they all have their own idea of how their Doctor should be.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indications are... [not much](https://www.digitalspy.com/tv/cult/a187072/david-tennant-i-didnt-have-story-input/)

> David Tennant has said that he never offered his input into Doctor Who stories because Russell T. Davies did not need it.

> TENNANT: Because Russell's writing it it would be foolish of me to start telling him what to do. Maybe if he ran out of inspiration or something, but wait until you see these final stories. They're just incredible.

[This Pinterest entry](https://www.pinterest.com/pin/3237030965689136/) purports that Peter Capaldi said this

> Q: "Do you provide character input?"
> PC: "It doesn't work like that. You just show up and do it. It's what you do with it."
> #PCapInYYC

Jodie Whittaker has made no comments, largely [because she is friends with Chris Chibnall](https://www.usatoday.com/story/entertainment/tv/2021/07/30/doctor-who-jodie-whittaker-showrunner-chris-chibnall-leaving-show/5426961001/), the director of her tenure as The Doctor.

> Chibnall, who took the reins at the same time, said he and Whittaker “made a ‘three series and out’ pact with each other at the start of this once-in-a-lifetime blast.”

Comment: The "3-and-out" pact is Great News!

Comment: @FreeMan it was announced that they're both leaving some time ago.

Comment: @OrangeDog I really don't follow the news of the show. I just watch (or try to for the last 2 Doctors...)